# Spearman rank correlation - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, typeerror

```
studlst = [['ABDIHAFITH', 8, 16, 19, 20, 3, 25, 16, 2, 9], ['ADAM', 12, 9, 17, 24, 13, 6, 15, 13, 30]

spearman = []

    dsquare = 0.0
    count = 0
    i = 0

    while i < len(studlst):
        dsquare += (studlst[i][1] - studlst[i][count+2])**2
        i += 1
        if i == len(studlst):
            count += 1
            spear = 1-((6*dsquare)/(len(studlst)(len(studlst)**2-1)))
            spearman.append(spear)
            if len(spearman) == (len(studlst[0])-2):
                break
            i = 0
            dsquare = 0
```

I keep getting the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". For the line creating the spear value (spermans rank correlation). I've tried converting the two len(studlst) on that line to float but it returns the same error replacing float with int. What should i do? Thanks

EDIT:
Problem stemmed from wrong syntax, was supposed to multiply len(studlst) and the brackets

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `len(studlst)(len(studlst)**2-1))` to mean?

Comment: Hint: Why did you *not* write `(6)(dsquare)`? That wouldn't work either; presumably you already understand why.

Comment: problem stemmed in that I meant to multipl len(studlst) and the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part looks problematic:

```py
len(studlst)(len(studlst)**2-1)
```

`len` produces an int, and the following parenthesized expression is parsed as a call.

If you mean to take a product, use the * operator:

```py
len(studlst) * (len (studlst)**2 - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the part `(len(studlst)(len(studlst)**2-1))`

evaluates to `int(some_value)` because `(len(studlst)` will give you an `int` and `(len(studlst)**2-1)` will be some value.

So you have `int(some_value)` as the end product of your code, which means you are treating `int` as some kind of function and calling it with some value like

`foo(x):
    pass`

and then `foo(0)`.

This is causing the problem. If you intend to multiply then change the equation to `(len(studlst) * (len(studlst)**2-1))`.